# SQLException: No suitable driver found for org.sqlite.JDBC

Tags: java, sqlite, exception

I am trying to run a code, which connect to SQLite database, using an Ant builder. When connecting I recieve a "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for org.sqlite.JDBC".

I put jar-connecter into "lib" folder, but not sure if I correctly described it in build.xml. Can you please point me into error.

My ant build.xml file snippet:

```
<target name="copy-res" description="Copying resources">
    <copy todir="${classes.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${res.dir}"/>
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="build" depends="compile, copy-res" description="Build all samples"/>

<target name="run" depends="build" description="Runs sample">
    <java classname="ViewConsole" fork="true" classpathref="sqlite.classpath">
     <classpath>
      <pathelement path="${classes.dir}"/>
     </classpath>
    </java>
</target>

 <!-- sqlite driver directory -->
<path id="sqlite.classpath">
 <fileset dir="lib">
  <include name="sqlite-jdbc-3.15.1.jar"/>
 </fileset>
</path>
```

The way I trying to connect to database:

```
    private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.sqlite.JDBC";
    Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
    System.out.println("Connection to database...");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_DRIVER);
    System.out.println("Connection is ok")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing an inappropriate value to `DriverManager.getConnection`. It's meant to be a JDBC URL - you're just passing in a class name.

The JDBC URL for SQLite would be something like

```
"jdbc:sqlite:/home/leo/work/mydatabase.db"
```

Comment: thanks, it helped! but now i got Class not found java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jdbc:sqlite:resources/SQLPlanner.db

Comment: Are you passing that to `Class.getClass`? It sounds like it. I didn't suggest changing that line... although I suspect you don't need it at all. Basically, `Class.forName` takes a class name, `DriverManager.getConnection` takes a JDBC URL. Those are pretty much never going to be the same thing...

Comment: i was sending it to Class.forName(), you're right. now with DriverManager.getConnection() it finally works. thank you very much!